# how to prove that this weak solution is subharmonic?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

My question is about  this article http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf.

My question is :

Consider a smooth, bounded and convex domain $K$ in $R^n$ such that $K\subset \{ x_1 = 0 \}$ and $\Omega $ a bounded convex domain  such that $\partial \Omega \supset K$.

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ a weak solution of the problem :
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\Delta u = 0,  \ in \  \Omega  \\
u = 1 \ in \  K \\
u = 0 \  on  \ \partial \Omega - K  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

In the page 4 the authors say : $|\nabla u|²$ is subharmonic (i believe that is in the weak sense). I dont know to how to show this .. Someone can give me a help to prove (or say to me a book with the proof)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not just in the weak sense: $|\nabla u|^2$ is $C^\infty$ smooth because $u$ is.

Comment: why $|\nabla u |²$ is $C^{\infty} ?$

Comment: It's the sum of squares of derivatives of $u$.

Comment: in this case $u \in H^{1}(\Omega) $ implies $u$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: No. $u$ being harmonic implies $u $ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: but $u$ is harmonic in the weak sense , not in the classic sense

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl's_lemma_(Laplace_equation)

Comment: i dont knew the Weyl lemma , thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the following facts:

1. If $u$ is harmonic, then the partial derivatives of $u$ are harmonic.
2. If $u$ is harmonic and $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is convex, then  $\phi\circ u$ is subharmonic.
3. The function $\phi(t)=t^2$ is convex.
4. $|\nabla u|^2$ is the sum of squares of partial derivatives of $u$.

Any book that deals with subharmonic functions should have some version of 2 in it. If $\phi$ is smooth (as it is here), you can do direct computation, but it's not much fun. It's better to prove the sub-mean-value property of $\phi\circ u$ using [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form).